# ReactJS | Show or Hide Array of Objects based on flag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, es6-map

**The Problem:**
What I am trying to do is hide/show react elements that are constructed dynamically based on a property of the Object Constructed. To be more precise let's take the following Array of Objects:

```
const Apps = [
  {name: App1, permission: ViewApp1},
  {name: App2, permission: ViewApp2},
  {name: App3, permission: ViewApp3},
  {name: App4 },
]
```

I want to `map` through them, and for each item, create a `nav-item`, in my NavBar.

Here is the `jsx code` for that:

```
const ScreenModule = ({ apps = [], currentRoute }) => (
  <Fragment>
    {apps.map(app => (
      <li
        key={app.name}
        title={app.name}
      >
        <a href={getUrlLink(app)}>
          <span>{app.name}</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    ))}
  </Fragment>
);
```

Now, usually when I want to check when to show an element, I wrap that jsx element, in the following utility function:

```
const AuthViewAdminManagement = ConditionalLoader(({ user }) =>
  // user = The currently loggedIn user
  userHasPermission(user, [
    Role.ViewApp1 // My ConstantArray of Permissions to check against
  ])
);
```

That is for a static element. **My problem lies on how to do the exact same thing for my dynamically constructed apps.**

**Basically, I am trying to find a way to wrap the li conditionally, based on the `name` or the `permission`.**

Also, how to deal with `App4` that doesn't have permission. How to show/hide that one in the map.

**I thought about using a filter, filtering for specific permissions or name, but I got stuck.**

I hope I made clear what my problem is. If you can help, it would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter:

```
const ScreenModule = ({ apps = [], currentRoute }) => (
  <Fragment>
    {apps.filter(app => app.permission).map(app => {
       return <li
         key={app.name}
         title={app.name}
       >
         <a href={getUrlLink(app)}>
           <span>{app.name}</span>
         </a>
       </li>
     })}
  </Fragment>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help you

```
const ScreenModule = ({ apps = [], currentRoute }) => (
  <Fragment>
    {apps.map(app => {
     return (app.permission ? 
      <li
        key={app.name}
        title={app.name}
      >
        <a href={getUrlLink(app)}>
          <span>{app.name}</span>
        </a>
      </li>:null)
     })}
  </Fragment>
);
```